# How do I remove case sensitivity from an entire Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, case-insensitive

I have a fairly complex Rails app built on top of Twitter's API, and want to make the whole app case-insensitive.

Up until now, we've been converting all usernames and other strings to .downcase whenever possible and using the default case-sensitive searches, but that's starting to cause problems, with 'Username' and 'username' being considered different users.

Do I need to set this validation:

validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false

somewhere on every one of my models (there are a lot) and remove all instances of .downcase from the app (there are a TON)? Any other ideas?

Note: this app isn't live yet, so I don't mind wiping all the data it's storing right now, if necessary.

Comment: Be very careful if you use the uniqueness validator without case sensitivity. It will just use LOWER() on the username field, causing it to skip the index you have on it (since the non-lowercase version is the one that's indexed). The workaround to this is to create a functional index (I hope you're using postgres).

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what the problem is.

I'm not sure how you're interfacing with the Twitter API, but I would just do the modification there. As in, when the username gets pulled from the Twitter API, downcase it immediately. This way you won't have to manually do it through all your models.

Comment: Well, part of the question is: does it make more sense to downcase everything (as you're suggesting), or would it be better to just make the whole app case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using Rack Middleware, see this page: http://gehling.dk/2010/02/how-to-make-rails-routing-case-insensitive/

UPDATE: This code has been updated to work with Rails 3 as well, so still a very good option.

Comment: Hi kateray. I know this is an old question, but since I am the author of the middleware solution, that you used, I just wanted to let you know, that I've finally made it into a gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting a filter on the create option that converts all the data to downcase BEFORE validation? Then, all the data would be assumed to be in downcase. Otherwise, just write a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a mixin that had your common validations like that username validation, add the case insensitivity, and just mix that in to all your models.